# A little help here with Action Script 3

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, flash-cs5

Well to cut the chase, I believe that this function is causing my problem.

```
function getRandomLabel():String {
    var labels:Array = new Array(24,62,49,74,37);
    var index:Number = Math.floor(Math.random() * labels.length);
    return labels[index];
}
this.gotoAndPlay(getRandomLabel());
```

This function is used for randomization of the 5 digits above (24,62,49,74,37)
So that my moles (5 moles) will appear randomly.
Currently working on a whack-a-mole flash game

**Current scene: 2 out of 3**

**Somehow, when I test play it it loops back to scene 1 frame 1.**

One more thing, the problem started when I tried to put the "game proper" into scene 2 where the rest of my codes are in (menu, mechanics, etc.)

Comment: What is the connection to Java?  That looks more like Javascript.

Comment: @AndrewThompson: It is ActionScript 3 code.

Comment: @david Thanks for clarifying.  I wish newbies would take more care to so much as understand what tools they are working with.  It is no wonder they cannot answer their own questions.  ..Not that this one even asked a question.

Comment: @AndrewThompson: I agree with you Andrew!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Andrew said, you don't have asked nothing. You just expose what you have but did not what is happening. Well, your function does not have problem. I'm pretty rusty with AS, but I would write it this way:

```
function getRandomFrame( frameNumbers: Array ): int {
    return frameNumbers[Math.floor( Math.random() * frameNumbers.length )];
}
gotoAndPlay( getRandomFrame( [24, 62, 49, 74, 37] ) );
```

You are getting frame numbers not labels, so I changed its name. Since you are calling gotoAndPlay, your movie "play head" will go to the selected frame and it will be played until it reaches the end of the timeline, and the movie, by default, will start over. If you need to stop the animation, you need to set an stop in the desired frame. Try your code with gotoAndStop instead of gotoAndPlay. The movie will go to the random frame and it will stop. If you need to get frame labels, create an array of Strings:

```
function getRandomLabel( labels: Array ): String {
    return labels[Math.floor( Math.random() * labels.length )];
}
gotoAndPlay( getRandomLabel( ["car", "dog", "music"] ) );
```

It seems that you are a Flash newbie, so you need to study more the tool that you are dealing with ;) The ActionScript default version in Flash CS5 is the third.

Comment: My bad really that I haven't asked anything. Yes, I'm a newbie to Flash, just started 2 days ago. We're a group actually, I didn't formulate that function. Anyway, thanks for your recommendation It worked. I just replaced 'int' with 'number' because apparently we're using AS 2.